# SSAS changing from multidimensional to tabular error

Tags: sql-server, ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

I've got a installed SQL Server 2014 instance BI edition.
I wanted to change deployment mode from 0 to 2 (multi -> tabular).
And i got this error when restarting the ssas-service in "services":

[image]

Anyone stumbled on this error before?

Comment: SSAS multidimension and tabular are 2 different instances if you install them both. What do you try to do?

Comment: trying to change deployment mode in msmdsrv.ini -file

Answer (score 2):

You tried to use multidimensional mode configuration file to configure tabular mode. ???

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/server-properties/general-properties

**DeploymentMode**

This property is configured by SQL Server Setup based on the server mode you selected when installing Analysis Services. This property should be considered internal only, always using the value specified by Setup.

Each mode is exclusive of the other. A server that is configured for tabular mode cannot run Analysis Services databases that contain cubes and dimensions.